# Summation of a series with continuous increase

Tags: summation

I am working on a summation of series.

Here is the Series

1- 10
0, 10 , 20, 30, 40 , 50, 60 ,70, 80, 90

11-20
100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280

21-30
300,340,380,420,460,500,540,580,620,660

As one can see, first diff is 10, second is 20 then 40 and next will be 80.

I want to perform a summation formula e.g if i place x = 54 i will get summation unto that point

I have tried doing stuff with n(n+1)/2 and similar summation formulae but can't get this thing in my mind yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(n)$ be the $n$th number you add.  The first thing to figure out is $A(10n+1)$ because things change there.  Since the sum of powers of $2$ up to $2^n$ is $2^{n+1}-1$ we have $A(10n+1)=100(2^n-1)$

Then from $A(10n+1)$ to $A(10n+10)$ the increment is $10\cdot 2^n$.

The sum of elements from $A(10n+1)$ through $A(10n+10)$ is then $10A(10n+1)+45 \cdot 10 \cdot 2^n=1000(2^n-1)+450\cdot 2^n=1450\cdot 2^n-1000$.

The sum of all the elements up to $A(10n+10)$ is $1450(2^{n+1}-1)-1000(n+1)$

The sum of the elements from $A(10n+1)$ through $A(10n+m)$ is $100m(2^n-1)+\frac 12m(m-1)10\cdot 2^n=100m(2^n-1)+5m(m-1)\cdot 2^n$

So to get $A(k)$, express $k$ as $10n+m$ with $1 \le m \le 10$ and

$A(10n+m)=1450(2^{n}-1)-1000(n)+100m(2^n-1)+5m(m-1)\cdot 2^n$

Comment: @MuhammadUmar:  I realized I was off one in the $n$s in the last equation.  That is because to get $A(10n+m)$ I need to sum first up to $A(10(n-1)+10)$

Comment: perfect, i fixed that already. Thanks tho. You really solved a great problem :)

Comment: @MuhammadUmar:  Now the last doesn't work for n=0 because the earlier doesn't work for $n=-1$